# Splitting file into smaller files by lines

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to figure out a way to split a big txt file with columns of data into smaller files for uploading purposes. The big file has 4000 lines and I wondering if there is a way to divide it into four parts such as

```
file 1 (lines 1-1000)

file 2 (lines 1001-2000)

file 3 (lines 2001-3000)

file 4 (lines 3001-4000)
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: What are you looking for here? Iterate through the lines. count while doing so. Output to buffer. at line 1001 close file writer. rinse repeat. http://whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: If you use linux you could just use the simple `split` command like this: `split -l 1000 file.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

This works (you could implement a `for` rather than a `while` loop but it makes little difference and does not assume how many files will be necessary):

```
with open('longFile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

threshold=1000
fileID=0
while fileID<len(lines)/float(threshold):
    with open('fileNo'+str(fileID)+'.txt','w') as currentFile:
        for currentLine in lines[threshold*fileID:threshold*(fileID+1)]:
            currentFile.write(currentLine)
        fileID+=1
```

Hope this helps. Try to use `open` in a `with` block as suggested in [python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
fhand = open(filename, 'r')
all_lines = fhand.readlines()

for x in xrange(4):
    new_file = open(new_file_names[x], 'w')
    new_file.write(all_lines[x * 1000, (x + 1) * 1000])
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Aleksander Lidtke's, but with a for loop and a pop() twist for fun. I also like to maintain some of the files original naming when I do this, since it is usually to multiple files. So I added the name "split" in it.

```
with open('Data.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

limit=1000
for o in range(len(lines)):
    if lines!=[]: 
        with open(f.name.split(".")[0] +"_" + str(o) + '.txt','w') as NewFile:
                for i in range(limit):
                    if lines!=[]:NewFile.write(lines.pop(0))
```